# Allow alphanumeric with spanish regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I tried the following code in javascript,

```
if(/[^0-9a-zñáéíóúü]/i.test(string))
{
    alert("oK WITH THE INPUT");
}
else
{
    alert("error");
}
```

But I am getting a result OK , even I entered the @ characters in my string. I dont why.

My aim is to allow alphanumeric(English and spanish).

Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't jquery; that's just plain javascript; fixed(edited) to that end.

Comment: "spanish regex", sounds kinky!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(/^[0-9a-zñáéíóúü]+$/i.test(string))
{
    alert("oK WITH THE INPUT");
}
else
{
    alert("error");
}
```

- Make the regex match more than one character with [the `+` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- Make it match the entire input with `^` and `$` anchors
- Don't [negate the character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) (remove the `^`)

Comment: @now its working  in jsfiddle .But when I am including into my page I am not getting the result.Could you please help in this ,I am seeing some strange charcters in browser?

Comment: Make sure you're saving **and serving** the JS file (or page containing the JS) in the same encoding, preferably UTF-8.

Comment: I added this question in seperate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246076/spanish-characters-not-coming-properly-in-javascript/17246109 .could you please take a look at this page.