# spanish characters not coming properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, multilingual

Hi I am using the following regular expression.It works fine in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wYJj5/).

```
                     var string="zñáéíóúü1111";

                       if(/^[0-9a-zñáéíóúü]+$/i.test(string))
                {
                    $("#result").text("oK WITH THE INPUT");

                }
                else
                {
                        $("#result").text("error");

                }
```

But when I put the code in browser the spanish characters not coming proprely(Some strange characters) (view source code in browser). and the above regular expression not working properly.

But I have the

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

in the browser.

I am not sure about the reason why its not working on my page , when I am getting the input from the user.But I put alert and checked the characters in this string .Both are same.

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @elclanrs no luck, I added it and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your HTML or JS file or both of them are not saved as UTF-8. You should adjust your editor's charset settings. Depending on the editor you might find them in the save dialog or the files' properties.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link
http://character-code.com/spanish-html-codes.php

for n = &nacute;
for i = &iacute;